# Remove overlapping paths from a file

Tags: bash

I have 2 local SVN working copy, /copyA and /copyB. I need to merge this two folders in one /copyA+B, and to keep this merged folder up to date, as long as commits flows in copyA and copyB.

To do that, I created a script that run a "svn diff --summarize" command on each source. The command give a result like this: a list of path, one path per line (i removed the first letter for simplification, and let's say there is no deletion).

```
path1
path1/file1
path2/file2
path3/file3
path3/folder1
path3/folder1/file4
path3/folder2/file5
```

This file is used to lauch a copy to /copyA+B, for each path in the file.

Some item are copied multiple time, for example line 1 copy the entire "path1" folder, but then line 2 copy file1 in "path1" again.

In this example, line 2 and line 6 are useless.

I want to write a bash script that will remove useless lines of the file.

How would you do that in bash ?
Note that the file can contains more than ten thousand lines.

Comment: a better question may be how you got that input...

Comment: @ReutSharabani this input is the output of a "svn diff --summarize" command

Comment: ok, why are you issuing a `cp` on `svn diff --summarize`? What are you trying to achieve? I'd add that to the question.

Comment: @ReutSharabani i tried to give more information about that in the question. Let me know if it needs more clarifications

Comment: Or, just use `rsync -uav --no-R --files-from=yourdifffile /full/path/to/copyA+B`. `rsync` will simply ignore files that already exist and not copy a second time unless the file being copied is newer than the one in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short **`sort`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
sort file | awk '$0 ~ "^"r"\\/"{ next }{ r=$0 }1'
```

- `sort file` - sort filepaths so that each directory path and its subordinate items will be grouped with directory path being first
- `{ r=$0 }` - capture the current line into variable `r` (directory path)
- `$0 ~ "^"r"\\/"{ next }` - if current line `$0` starts with a pattern of previously captured directory path `r` - skip the record with `next` operator

---

The output:

```
path1
path2/file2
path3/file3
path3/folder1
path3/folder2/file5
```

Comment: It works fine and pretty fast on 150000 lines, less than 2 seconds !

Comment: @aurya, yes, see my explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
grep -Fvf <(sed 's:$:/:' svnDiff) svnDiff
```

#### Explanation

`sed 's:$:/:' svnDiff` appends `/` at the end of each line. The result is then passed on to `grep`.
`grep -Fvf ... svnDiff` keeps only those lines from `svnDiff` that do not match (`-v`) any literal string `(-F)` from the "file" produced by sed `(-f)`.

### Problems

We have to ensure that `grep` matches only at the beginning of a line. We could to this with

```
grep -Evf <(sed 's:^:^;s:$:/:' svnDiff) svnDiff
```

but then characters like `*` in the paths would be treated as wildcards by `grep`. We could escape them by extending the `sed` part, but `grep` has a lot of special characters.

Comment: Tested on 150000 lines, it gives the right result in less than 3 seconds